# Activate and deactivate preloader page when php file has started and finished loading respectively

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a html form with a php file that is actioned on submission. I want to activate a preloader page (showing the client to be patient) that will then be deactivated when php form has finished loading. I have created the preloader in css. Anyone who can help please?

Comment: Yes, something with `javascript`, so you've tagged the right resources. It's now time for you to write some code, if you then come up to a problem that you can't solve, then you can start asking here. Search engines are you friend here aswell, almost anything has been asked before!

Comment: Thanks. I have actually written some code. My problem occurs with the javascript. I have tried some jquery but I am struggling to get it to work and it mostly not understanding how it actually works. Heres the jquery I wrote.

function loader() {
  showLoad();
  $.ajax(url).complete(function(data) {
      hideLoading();
      console.log(data);
   });
}

showload() and hideload() are supposed to control the preloader

Comment: Please *edit* your question, don't put code in the comments, makes it really hard to follow problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>//paste this code under the head tag or in a separate js file.

// Wait for window load

$(window).load(function() {

// Animate loader off screen

$(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");;

});</script>

<body>

<div class="se-pre-con"></div>

<style> 
.se-pre-con {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url(../images/Preloader_11.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
}
</style>
```